# Updating state of different instances of the same component using React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have two instances of a component which I want them to behave like toggle buttons. If I click on a specific component instance, the other component instances should get deselected.

[image]

The below is my code:

store.js:

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import boxReducer from './slices/boxSlice'

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    box:boxReducer
  }
})
```

boxSlice.js:

```js
export const boxSlice = createSlice({
  name: "box",
  initialState: {
      selected: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    select: (state) => {
    state.selected=true;
    },
    deselect: (state) => {
        state.selected=false;
    },
  },
});

export const { select, deselect } = boxSlice.actions;
export default boxSlice.reducer;
```

Box.js:

```
export function Box(){
  const selectedStatus = useSelector((state) => state.box.selected)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("Unselected")

  const onSelect = (e) => {
    dispatch(select());
    if (selectedStatus) {
      setStatus("Selected")
      dispatch(deselect());
    } else {
      setStatus("Unselected");
    }
  }

  return (
    <div tabIndex="0" onClick={onSelect} className="box">
      {status}
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is buggy. What I am observing is:

- On first click the instance does not get updated. It gets updated only on second click
- It does not toggle properly. Both remain selected or unselected

How do I update the other instances of the component properly, whenever one of the instances is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redux state should be the source of truth. I suggest giving each box component a unique id and store the currently selected box id. If the same box id is already selected, deselect the box id, otherwise, set to the new id.

Example:

boxSlice.js

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const boxSlice = createSlice({
  name: "box",
  initialState: {
    selected: null
  },
  reducers: {
    select: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.selected = state.selected === payload ? null : payload;
    }
  }
});

export const { select } = boxSlice.actions;
export default boxSlice.reducer;
```

Box

```
function Box({ id }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const selected = useSelector((state) => state.box.selected);
  const isSelected = selected === id;

  const onSelect = () => {
    dispatch(select(id));
  };

  return (
    <div tabIndex="0" onClick={onSelect} className="box">
      {isSelected ? "Selected" : "Unselected"}
    </div>
  );
}
```

App

```
<Box id={1} />
<Box id={2} />
```

[image: Edit updating-state-of-different-instances-of-the-same-component-using-react-redux]

Comment: This works very well. However, if I click on an already selected box, it should not toggle. It should toggle only when other instances are clicked.  How would I do that?

Comment: @codingsplash I see, to do that simply set the selected id to the payload, e.g. `state.selected = payload`, this way a box id is never deselected, only overwritten. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of maintaining a separate `state` in your component, you can make use of the Redux state returned by the `useSelector`

Try to click on the "Selected" and "Unselected" below to see it works:

```
export function Box({ inverse }) {
  const selected = useSelector((state) => state.box.selected);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onSelect = () => {
    if (selected) {
      dispatch(deselect());
    } else {
      dispatch(select());
    }
  };

  const actualSelected = inverse ? !selected : selected;

  return (
    <div tabIndex="0" onClick={onSelect} className="box">
      {actualSelected ? 'Selected' : 'Unselected'}
    </div>
  );
}

<Box />
<Box inverse />
```

After that, you can have another boolean flag (eg. `inverse`) to know that which of the 2 box's component should be inversed.

```js
const { useState } = React;
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createSlice, configureStore } = RTK;

const boxSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'box',
  initialState: {
    selectedId: 0
  },
  reducers: {
    select: (state, action) => {
      state.selectedId = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

const { select } = boxSlice.actions;
const boxReducer = boxSlice.reducer;
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    box: boxReducer
  }
});

const Box = () => {
  // Random generate ID for this box. For React 18+, you can consider using useId() instead
  // Saving in state instead of memo ensures the value will always stay the same
  const [randomId] = useState(() => Math.random());
  const selectedId = useSelector((state) => state.box.selectedId);
  const isSelected = selectedId === randomId;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onSelect = () => {
    dispatch(select(randomId));
  };

  return (
    <div tabIndex="0" onClick={onSelect} className="box">
      {isSelected ? 'Selected' : 'Unselected'}
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Box />
    <Box />
    <Box />
    <Box />
    <Box />
  </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

```css
.box {
  padding: 16px 32px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-right: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/redux@4.2.1/dist/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-redux@7.2.9/dist/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reduxjs/toolkit@1.9.5/dist/redux-toolkit.umd.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: How would you handle toggling between more than two boxes?

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, using ID is definitely a better option, let me modify my code to randomly generate an ID as well so it can support multiple instances :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
  export function Box(){
  const selectedStatus = useSelector((state) => state.box.selected)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("Unselected")

  const onSelect = (e) => {
    dispatch(select());
    if (selectedStatus) {
      setStatus("Unselected")
      dispatch(deselect());
    } else {
      setStatus("Selected");
      dispatch(select());
    }
  }

  return (
    <div tabIndex="0" onClick={onSelect} className="box">
      {status}
    </div>
  )
}
```